# Sessions are not persisting in the database for each user in same browser with different tabs using Spring Sessions with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I'm currently using db (mysql) to store my sessions with spring. It is generating new session id for each user but it is replacing session id's of previously who are logged. Please give some suggestions to overcome this problem.
The following the service which is I am calling from controller for each request

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhytO.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTTFa.png)

```
public class MultiLoginServiceImpl
{
        public static String createMultiLogin(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
        {

                String alias = httpRequest.getParameter("_s");
                System.err.println("alias"+alias);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

            SessionRepository<Session> sessionRepository =(SessionRepository<Session>) httpRequest.getAttribute(SessionRepository.class.getName());

                Map<String, String> sessionIds = sessionManager.getSessionIds(httpRequest);
                System.out.println(sessionIds);
                for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sessionManager.getSessionIds(httpRequest).entrySet()) {

                    String aliasId = entry.getKey();
                    String sessionId = entry.getValue();
                    HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);
                    Session storedSession = sessionRepository.getSession(sessionId);
                    if(storedSession.getAttribute("userEmailId")!= null)
                    {
                        httpSession.setAttribute("userEmailId", storedSession.getAttribute("userEmailId"));
                    }
                    System.out.println("mapids"+aliasId +" : "+sessionId);
                }

                String addAlias = alias== null ? newSessionAlias1: requestedSessionAlias1; 

                /*if(alias == null || "".equals(alias.trim()))
                {
                        alias = sessionManager.getNewSessionAlias(httpRequest);
                }*/
                httpRequest.setAttribute("alias",addAlias);
                //SecurityContext context = (SecurityContext) httpSession.getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
                //System.out.println(context.toString());
                String addAccountUrl = sessionManager.encodeURL(httpRequest.getContextPath(), addAlias); 
                System.out.println("addalias"+addAlias);
                return addAccountUrl ;

        }
}
```

Comment: Typically multiple tabs in the same browser share the same set of cookies.  If you open a new browser tab and create a new session, it overwrites the session from the first tab on the client side.

Comment: Yes if we open new browser means it will not share but my requirement is in same browser .

Comment: Your requirement is to change the ingrained behaviour of all browsers?  Good luck man!

Comment: My requirement is not to change the ingrained behavior of all browsers.Just to allow the multiple logins like google add account and switching account from one to another.

Comment: Then you have to manage multiple active sessions on the client.